# Magento coupon report returns “No records found for this period”?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have to tried generate a coupon report from Magento backend, in option reports->sales->coupon. But it shows a "no record found" error. I also checked it in database, there are all entries are in "Salesrule Coupon" table.

Comment: This question was answered as having a problem with its Cron jobs, but the answer was so brief it was deleted by folks in the Review Queue. I think the question can be closed as lacking an [mcve] or unreproducible.